# setInterval() does not work on style.marginLeft

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want the box I have created to move 20px every .5 seconds but it happens only once with `setInterval()`

```
 <style type="text/css">
            #box{
                background-color: green;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="box"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(function(){
                push();
            },500);
            function push(){
                var box = document.getElementById('box');
                box.style.marginLeft="20px";
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: You're setting the `marginLeft` value over and over to the same value.  You have to increment the value you set it to over time if you want the box to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 20 extra pixel every iteration

```js
            setInterval(function(){
                push();
            },500);
            function push(){
                var box = document.getElementById('box');
                box.style.marginLeft= parseInt(box.style.marginLeft||0) + 20 + "px";
            }
```

```css
 #box{
                background-color: green;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the push function needs to be modified

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function(){
            push();
        },500);
        function push(){
            var box = document.getElementById('box'),
            margin=parseFloat(box.style.marginLeft);

            box.style.marginLeft=(margin+20)+"px";
        }
    </script>
```